# How can I fix this DirectoryNotFoundException?

Tags: c#, wpf, path

I have a DirectoryNotFoundException on a .txt file if I use the full path it's working but I don't want to use the full path because I want the program work no matter where it is placed (compatibilty with the maximum of computer)

Here's my code

```
private void SaveClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Windowed.IsChecked == true)
        windowed = true;
    else
        windowed = false;

    string textWriteWindowed;

    if (windowed == true)
    {
        textWriteWindowed = "-screen-fullscreen 0" + Environment.NewLine;
    }
    else
    {
        textWriteWindowed = "-screen-fullscreen 1" + Environment.NewLine;
    }

    var selectedResolution = ResolutionBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
    var split = selectedResolution.Split('x');
    widthChoose = Int32.Parse(split[0]);
    heightChoose = Int32.Parse(split[1]);

    string textWriteWidth;
    textWriteWidth = "-screen-width " + widthChoose + Environment.NewLine;

    string textWriteHeight;
    textWriteHeight = "-screen-height " + heightChoose + Environment.NewLine;

    File.WriteAllText(@"\Resources\arguments.txt", textWriteWindowed);
    File.AppendAllText(@"\Resources\arguments.txt", textWriteWidth);
    File.AppendAllText(@"\Resources\arguments.txt", textWriteHeight);

    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: When you get instant downvote ;-;

Comment: Try to check first, if the directory exists [Directory.Exists method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.directory.exists(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The "arguments.txt" is in a folder named "Ressources" next to my program I don't understand why it tells me that, how should I write it ?

Comment: but this is referencing c:\Resources

Comment: try File.WriteAllText("../../Resources/arguments.txt", textWriteWindowed);

Comment: @UthistranS. Omg thank you man <3

Comment: **Do not** use "../../" as start of a relative path, as this only makes sense in the default output directory structure of a Visual Studio project, where the output is generated to e.g. "bin/Debug/" (which can even be changed). To make it work everywhere, you should *create* the Resources directory in the current working directory of the application if it isn't existing.

Comment: Yes you are right haha, can you tell me how to do what you expained ?

Comment: (Nearly) as shown in the answer. Check `Directory.Exists("Resources")`, otherwise create it by `Directory.CreateDirectory("Resources")`.

Comment: Hmm I don't have error but the txt file don't get edited  `Directory.CreateDirectory("Resources");
            File.WriteAllText("./Resources/arguments.txt", textWriteWindowed);
            File.AppendAllText("./Resources/arguments.txt", textWriteWidth);
            File.AppendAllText("./Resources/arguments.txt", textWriteHeight);`

Comment: The folder is now in your application's *current directory*, e.g. `<project>/bin/Debug/Resources`.

Comment: @Francefire: If your folder ist named "Ressources" (with double 's') then you have have the source of your exception. In your code, it is written "Resources" (with one 's')

Comment: This is why I don't understand seems like I did everything like I should (I went in properties add the Resources from there)

Answer (score 4):

The first argument of `File.WriteAllText` takes a path as input. Whatever you have mentioned is not the absolute path but it is just the relative path of the file. `WriteAllText` creates the file but doesn't create the directory by itself. So something like:

```
File.WriteAllText(@"\arguments.txt", textWriteWindowed);
```

shall work (and create the file in the respective drive), but

```
File.WriteAllText(@"\Resources\arguments.txt", textWriteWindowed);
```

shall not work. Hence, if you want to create a file in the path where the application resides, you can do something like:

```
string folder=Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
File.WriteAllText(@"\arguments2.txt", "ABC");
```

If you want to create a directory, then you could do something like:

```
System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(filePath);
file.Directory.Create();// If the directory already exists, this method does nothing.

System.IO.File.WriteAllText(file.FullName, textWriteWindowed);
```

Hope this answers your query.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply, what is the ABC for ? and why "arguments**2**.txt"

Answer (score 0):

you have to check whether the folder is exist before save the file,

if folder not exist create it using

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(...)

Directory.Exists(..)
```

you can use to check folder existence

Comment: I don't know where to out them ^^'

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how but doing that worked for me :

```
 File.WriteAllText(@"./arguments.txt", textWriteWindowed);
            File.AppendAllText(@"./arguments.txt", textWriteWidth);
            File.AppendAllText(@"./arguments.txt", textWriteHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you wanted to get the local path of the file you are executing use this:

```
 var fInfo = new FileInfo(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().Location);
```

From there, you would do the following:

```
var parentDir = new DirectoryInfo(fInfo.DirectoryName);
var subDir = new DirectoryInfo(parentDir.FullName + "Resource");
if(!subDir.Exists)
   subDir.Create();
```

This would ensure that you always have a folder in the directory of your executable. But just so you know, this is absolutely horrible code and should never ever be implemented in a production like environment.  What if some knucklehead sysAdmin decides to place your program/folder in an area that the current user does not have access/writes too?  The best place to write to is %APPDATA%, this will ensure the user always has read/write permissions to what you are trying to accomplish.